# How to write this "C"?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, math-fonts

How can I write this different "C" in LaTeX? I've tried it in various ways using various fonts and I still haven't got something like that.

[image]

Comment: \complement symbol. The font Is euler.

Comment: As @Sebastiano says, but you need `\usepackage{amssymb}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Be so kind and show us, wat you (unsuccessful) try so far (in for od small but complete document).

Comment: This symbol is contained within the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](//texdoc.net/pkg/comprehensive) and is therefore a duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764)